# Extra wire with ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, wiring

We are replacing an old ceiling fan with a new Hunter ceiling fan.  The instructions say to connect the black wire in the new fan with the blue and black wire from the fixture.  There is an extra red wire.  What do we do with that?  Can we just cap it off?

Comment: Is the red wire in the electrical box or in the fan?

Comment: Difficult to say.  Fans come with several wirings, and homes have several styles of wiring to support different fan hookups.

Comment: Does this question help you out? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/30764/what-do-i-do-with-the-unused-wire-for-ceiling-fan-installation

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the fan and switch boxes please?